Drawing box in custom indicator for TradingView advance charting library
I am trying to draw a box as like we do in pinescript following some logic in my constructor function inside custom indicator getter function. But it seems we have only line plot field in there. What I need to do is to draw a box when at an index and when the logic is not satisfied anymore I delete that box. Can you help me please.
incorporating the Drawings API within custom_indicators_getter by creating a shape in the constructor and updating it within the main fn. no hope

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
